# Save regression results in latex and text

Tags: r, regression

I am using R and I need to save regression results in latex and text format. I would like to obtain something similar to what it's possible to achieve using stargazer package. The problem here is that I have a non standard regression but a two-step estimation with a table divided into coefficients and P-values for each variable specification. How can I achieve something similar to the last table (normal regression output) ? Thank you.

```
#table 1
var_name       |  estimate | P-val | Specification
1: (Intercept) | -0.01 | 0.786 |    1
2: var 1       |  0.27 | 0.001 |    1
3: var 2       | -0.32 | 0.000 |    1
4: var 3       | -0.24 | 0.001 |    1
5: var 4       | -0.14 | 0.000 |    1
6: var 5       |  0.08 | 0.009 |    1

#table 2
var_name       |  estimate | P-val | Specification
1: (Intercept) |  0.01 | 0.686 |    2
2: var 1       |  -0.37| 0.041 |    2
3: var 2       | -0.34 | 0.021 |    2
4: var 3       | -0.84 | 0.003 |    2
5: var 5       | -0.54 | 0.000 |    2
6: var 7       |  0.18 | 0.09  |    2

#need to obtain

--------------------------------------------
    Dependent Variable
        Var 0
--------------------------------------------
      (1)           (2)
Var1  -0.01         0.01
Var2   0.27***      -0.37
Var5                -0.54***
...
--------------------------------------------
Observations
...
```

Comment: have you tried with the function  xtable?

Comment: there are some interesting functions in the package ```texreg```, such as ```texreg()``` or ```screenreg()```. You should check if it corresponds to what you want to do

Comment: I will, thanks for the comments